# What is the best way to memory allocate

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to allocate memory in this situation, actually i did what i wanted but im wondering is there any better way or is there something i did wrong .

I just trying to code functional as much as possible what else can i do for this .

```
void createDATABASE(int uint_val,int int_val,int str_val,int dbl_val)
{
    int *decision=(int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    dbStore tdbStore;
    t_CreateDatabase tCreateDatabase;
    signal(SIGINT,err_memleak); // SIGNAL PROCESSING

    memcpy(tCreateDatabase.filename,"test.bin",32); // database name copied

    decision[0] = uint_val; decision[1] = int_val;
    decision[2] = str_val; decision[3] = dbl_val;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(decision[i] > 0){
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    tdbStore.unsig_int = u_intAllocate(uint_val);
                    if(tdbStore.unsig_int==NULL) raise(SIGINT);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tdbStore.sig_int = n_intAllocate(int_val);
                    if(tdbStore.sig_int==NULL) raise(SIGINT);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tdbStore.strings = strAllocate(str_val);
                    if(tdbStore.strings==NULL) raise(SIGINT);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tdbStore.big_int = d_intAllocate(dbl_val);
                    if(tdbStore.big_int==NULL) raise(SIGINT);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


}

char **strAllocate(int val)
{
    int column=1024,l;
    char **node = (char**)malloc(val*sizeof(char*));
    for(l=0;l<val;l++)
        node[l] = (char*)malloc(column*sizeof(char));
    return node;
}
double *d_intAllocate(int val)
{
    double *node = (double*)malloc(val*sizeof(double));
    return node;
}
unsigned int *u_intAllocate(int val)
{
    unsigned int *node = (unsigned int*)malloc(val*sizeof(unsigned int));
    return node;
}
int *n_intAllocate(int val)
{
    int *node = (int*)malloc(val*sizeof(int));
    return node;
}
```

Thanks for advises..

Comment: I think what you did is fine. Also currently `malloc` is normally used instead of `calloc`. is because there is a run-time cost for setting the memory to all-zeros.

Comment: @Jayesh that is system-dependent, e.g. on Linux it is faster to calloc than malloc in some situations

Comment: If you have code that is working but you want comments on it, post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion 1**

You can easily replace

```
int *decision=(int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
```

by

```
int decision[4];
```

When the size of an array is fixed, it makes no sense to use `malloc`.

**Suggestion 2**

Do not use explicit cast on the value returned from `malloc`.

Use

```
char **node = malloc(val*sizeof(char*));
```

instead of

```
char **node = (char**)malloc(val*sizeof(char*));
```

Using explicit cast on the returned value of `malloc` are known to be problematic. Checkout [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for details.

**Suggestion 3**

You can reduce the overhead of the string allocations by calling `malloc` only twice.

```
char **strAllocate(int val)
{
    int column=1024,l;
    char **node = malloc(val*sizeof(char*));
    char* data = malloc(val*column); // No need for sizeof(char). It is always 1.
    for(l=0;l<val;l++)
        node[l] = data + i*column;
    return node;
}
```

If you use this, you have to remember to call `free` only twice when the time comes to deallocate the memory.

```
free(*node);
free(node);
```